# Best practice in pointing multiple urls to same method in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-routing

Is there a better way of doing this in Laravel 4 without repeating code?

```
Route::get('site/{url}', 'SearchController@index');
Route::get('test1/{url}', 'SearchController@index');
Route::get('test2/{url}', 'SearchController@index');
```

i.e. pointing multiple urls to single method with query string values. What is the best practice to achieve this?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make it one route with a dynamic first segment and restrict that to a set of values with regex:

```
Route::get('{first}/{url}', 'SearchController@index')
     ->where('first', '(site|test1|test2)');
```